# Any way to run AWS Aurora locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We are thinking about migrating to AWS Aurora from MySql. We are running vagrant for developers, so each virtual box has its own mysql instance. Is there a way to run Aurora locally? If not, what would be the best way to handle the situation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is there any difference in the way you would use Aurora versus the way you are currently using MySQL? We have continued to use MySQL locally after migrating to Aurora on AWS.

Comment: I understand Aurora is fully compatible with mysql 5.6 and it's a drop-in replacement. I just don't like the fact that dev and prod environment use different database. Odd things happen due to different environment.

Comment: There is no local Aurora. Either use MySQL or have your devs connect to an Aurora instance for developing. You should have a test environment on AWS that would reveal any issues before you deploy to prod anyway.

Comment: In our case, we are using Aurora 5.6 compatible, and it accepts keys longer than 767 bytes (but real MySQL does not).  Thus migrations that are perfectly valid in Aurora (and are deployed and working) are broken locally.

Comment: There is a big difference between the two. We have test scripts that run locally and there are subtle differences between the different versions of MySQL, let alone comparing MySQL to Aurora. For example, some versions of MySQL have bugs that other ones don't. These are the types of things that you don't want popping up on a production system.

Comment: MySQL does not support reading/writing to/from S3, nor does it have native lambda functions, nor does it have all the special aurora stored procedures provided by AWS.

Comment: Instead of creating SSH tunnel, I am directly connecting to my Aurora Instance from PG Admin, it seems working fine locally. I am thinking it's compatible with both.

Comment: @gdmanandamohon there is nothing related to SSH tunnel in the question or any of the answers on this page. SSH tunnel would be required if you didn't enable the "publicly accessible" flag on your RDS instance. That is not at all related to what is being discussed here.

Answer (score 9):

You can continue to use mysql, since aurora is compatible with mysql. Aurora differs with mysql in other features such as autohealing, more read replicas, availability replication, performance and other non development related features.

Therefore for development mysql suits you.

The only problem I can think of is if you use the [lambda triggering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Lambda.html) feature.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Not a solution but re-statement of the Question asked above!

The major issue is when the downstream app is listening for activities on DB.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/DBActivityStreams.html#DBActivityStreams.AuditLog

The mock up service can go so far, so it will be great to have to a version of AWS Aurora as a local docker.